# Importing Weighted DNS records in google cloud dns

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dns, round-robin, google-cloud-dns

I'm facing challenge to import records from `AWS route53` service to `google cloud DNS`.
I felt `Route53` has many features compare to `google-cloud-dns` .

First, I faced challenge with root alias record which I'm going to deal with `CNAME` by using `www` or `www1` records .
Now, I'm facing challenge to import `Weighted` dns records in `google cloud dns`.
I dont see option to add different weights to DNS records in `google cloud`.
Also, I have some records which are with `weight 0` in `route53`.
I think those will not get traffic as I read on `route53` documentation.
So I have to remove and add them when needed in `clouddns` rather than keeping with `weight 0`
Looking for suggestions to solve this problem without using `load-balancer` .
Also, if someone got options to deal with `root alias record` in `gcp` `clouddns` please guide me.

thanks

thanks

Comment: There is no generic notion of "weight" in the DNS, except for specific records, so you depend on some specific local proprietary features, hence you will have problems migrating, either your current or new provider should help you, because your question is not related to programming and hence is offtopic here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only Google Cloud DNS resource record that supports priority/weight is MX records. The AWS Route 53 features are vendor added which Google Cloud DNS does not support